# Prometheus - Windows Exporter

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

Hi I have a issue regarding the metrics created from textfile collector in windows prometheus exporter.

```
    ---
# Note this is not an exhaustive list of all configuration values
collectors:
  enabled: cpu,cs,logical_disk,net,os,service,system,textfile,process
  textfile: C:\win_exporter\resolution
collector:
  service:
    services-where: Name='windows_exporter'
  process:
    names:
      - DesktopAutomationServiceControl
      - explorer
log:
  level: debug
  file: 'C:\win_exporter\windows_exporter.log'
scrape:
  timeout-margin: 0.5
telemetry:
  addr: ":9082"
  path: /metrics
```

max-requests: 5
Above can be found my YAML for windows exporter configuration.

In the path textfile there is a file resolution.prom which content is:

```
# HELP resolution_present Indicates if resolution is present in the file
# TYPE resolution_present gauge
resolution_present 0
```

There is an empty line after resolution_present 0 as per docs it's required but stackoverflow does not allow me to make an empty line in code.

Basically the whole issue is that in my prometheus do not get metrics from the textfile collector.
(Empty query result) after executing in PromQL...
The metrics file is generated by some PS script which checks resolution which runs periodically.

Or maybe you have completly other idea how to check resolution of the machine by using windows exporter.

I really appreciate your support.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `resolution_present` present in exporters page (http://localhost:9182)? And what is shown in logs?

Comment: A small side note: there is no need for empty line in the end. Textfile exporter requires you to have a newline symbol after last metric, that's all. Basically last symbol of file should not be a last digit of last metric's value, but rather `\`n`

Comment: @markalex - nah... that's the problem i do not see that metrics at all at promethus ui
Thanks for the tip will edit it :)

Comment: @markalex so the .prom file should look like this right?

# HELP resolution_present Indicates if resolution is present in the file
# TYPE resolution_present gauge
resolution_present 0`n

Comment: It's hard to explain through comments. Look at [example](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.textfile.md). You can see that no additional newlines added at the end. And just in case `\`n` is symbol of newline in my comment (like the one used in powershell), analogue to more popular `\n` in most other languages.

Comment: "i do not see that metrics at all at promethus ui" I'm asking if it can be seen on the windows_exporter's page. You can see it using browser and said address. And what is shown in logs?

Comment: @markalex I entered my windows exporter metrics site at the machine. 

And the resolution_present is not there. 

Any idea why? 

I will explain a little more how it looks at my end:

C:\win_exporter - here is located the config.yml

C:\win_exporter\resolution here we have resolution.prom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253848/discussion-between-ggrela-and-markalex).

Answer (score 0):

The files generated by PowerShell are not by default in UTF8 which my windows_exporter required.